# PHP array sort and skip underscore

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is by default sorted alphabetically.

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\_luke
    [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\_zod
    [2] => C:\xampp\htdocs\jess
    [3] => C:\xampp\htdocs\peter
)
```

My code will be something like this:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

- How can I sort it and skip the `_` character?
- I can't just remove the `_` because I still need it when I'm in the loop.
- I don't care about keeping the key numbers. I'm doing a foreach loop anyway.

**The result I'm looking for is this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\jess
    [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\_luke
    [2] => C:\xampp\htdocs\peter
    [3] => C:\xampp\htdocs\_zod
)
```

Comment: Use `usort` with an appropriate comparison, e.g. `ltrim($a, '_') <=> ltrim($b, '_')`.

Comment: Instead of integer keys, set the key value by folder name without under bar and ksort();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a fitted callback function to make comparisons.

Use it like this:

```
usort($array, function($elemA, $elemB) {
   return strcmp(str_replace("_", "", $elemA), str_replace("_", "", $elemB));
});
```

This will compare your elements using [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) but ignoring the underscore "_".

Comment: Note that this ignores *all* underscores in the entire string, not merely leading ones.

Comment: It does ignore _all_ underscores, as the OP didn't mention special parsing needed.

Comment: @Kleskowy I set your as an accepted answer. I also added my own take on it. It's a bit "cheaty" because I use some CMS helper functions to do it. However it's based on your code and then changed it alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = preg_replace('/\_/', '', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('/\_/', '', $b);

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

$array = Array
(
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\_luke',
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\_zod',
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\jess',
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\peter'
);

usort($array, "cmp");
print_r($array);
```

Use a helper method for "equalizing" the texts.

Answer (score 0):

I already set another answer as accepted but here is what I ended up with. It can give others a hint of how to only handle the first underscore.

```
usort($folders, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(
        ltrim(basename($a), '_'),
        ltrim(basename($b), '_')
    );
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what those helper functions add over `ltrim($a, '_')`, but okay… :)

Comment: @deceze It seems like you live on Stack Overflow. :) Anyway, your solution is correct as always and my code is much shorter now without the Kirby CMS dependency. Thanks!

Comment: Got a lot of short downtimes while code compiles… ;)